# A question about indexed intersections and unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show that $X\cup \underset{i}{\large\cap} Y_i=\underset{i}{\large\cap}(X\cup Y_i)$

This is what I got, but I just want to know if I am going about this the correct way.

$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned} \\
x\in X\cup \underset{i}{\large\cap} Y_i &\implies x\in X \vee x\in \underset{i}{\large\cap} Y_i \\
 &\implies x\in X \vee \forall i\in I  \ x\in Y_i \\
 &\implies \forall i\in I (x\in X \vee x\in Y_i) \\
&\implies x\in \underset{i}{\large\cap}(X\cup Y_i)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$.

Would this work for the one direction? I am a little skeptical about "moving" the forall statement in this section   $x\in X \vee \forall i\in I  \ x\in Y_i \implies \forall i\in I (x\in X \vee x\in Y_i)$. It seems obvious to me that this is OK, but I am not quite sure how to justify it.

Comment: Your argument is correct. Note that you only add the condition $x\in A$ what holds independently of $i\in I.$

Comment: you could add this as an answer, as you have answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the distributive law
$$
X \lor (Y_1 \land Y_2) = (X \lor Y_1) \land (X \lor Y_2)
$$
you can extend this by induction

added (see comment)

if we use $i,j$ to signify elements of $I$
$$
\forall j ( x \in \cap_i Y_i \implies x \in Y_j) \\
\forall j (x \in X \lor x \in \cap_iY_i \implies x \in X \lor x \in Y_j) \\
\forall j (x \in X \lor x \in \cap_iY_i \implies x \in ( X \cup  Y_j) ) \\
x \in X \lor x \in \cap_iY_i \implies \forall j (x \in ( X \cup  Y_j) )\\
x \in X \lor x \in \cap_iY_i \implies x \in \cap_j( X \cup  Y_j) 
$$

Comment: $I$ may not be countable

Comment: good point. i certainly don't think transfinite induction is what is needed! i'll  add a couple of thoughts to that useless answer.